# how to pass global variables to all components - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a shopping cart website and I should pass some value to all components. for example when the user logged in the website I stored some value of user to `localStorage`. now, most components need to know about these values.

my question is I should retrieve these values inside each component (inside `componentDidMount` function)?

of course I know about `redux`. but I have a problem with `redux` when the user refresh page I lose data.

Comment: I'm using`localStorage`. my question is I should retrieve a specific value each component?

Comment: You can load from localStorage and make that initial/pre-rendered store value. `const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,/);

Comment: `const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedStateFROM_LOCAL_STORAGE,
    middleWare);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use redux. You can persist and rehydrate the store to the local storage or IndexedDB using a store enhancer, such as [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

Another option is to use Use React's [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You can inject the data to the component's tree via the context provider, and all components would have access to it.

The context is described as:

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without
>   having to pass props down manually at every level.

Example of use (from React 16.3 documentation):

```
// Create a context for the current theme (with "light" as the default).
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Use a Provider to pass the current theme to the tree below.
    // Any component can read it, no matter how deep it is.
    // In this example, we're passing "dark" as the current value.
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
        <Toolbar />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

function ThemedButton(props) {
  // Use a Consumer to read the current theme context.
  // React will find the closest theme Provider above and use its value.
  // In this example, the current theme is "dark".
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {theme => <Button {...props} theme={theme} />}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need 16.0+ I think and 16.3+ has new way of doing things

Comment: This is the 16.3 version.

Comment: You'll need to do that for each component, and it will make testing harder, since you'll need to mock the localStorage. In addition, why do you another way to pass data besides props and context.

Comment: I think OP just need preloadedState (localStorage value) to be passed to the createStore or use library that you suggested.

Comment: If he uses redux, that's the way he should go. If he doesn't, the context is preferable.

Comment: That's the answer I think OP is looking for. LocalStorage fetching within individual component is not preferable